# Rearlights and terminology

Tags: mercedes-benz, part-identification, tail-lights

I'm a non-mechanic that's recently gotten hold of a second-hand rearlight for the Mercedes A-Class (W176), and I'm trying to make sense of the terminology I'm coming across in an attempt to determine how much it's worth and whether I've been conned.

Firstly, the label for the rear light that I bought states the following, and this is what made me initially suspicious after the purchase:

[image: picture of label]

Does "Tail Lamp Glass R." indicate that it's just the glass on its own, i.e. that it's missing something it shouldn't be?

I looked up the [product number here](https://www.rexbo.eu/van-wezel/combination-taillight-3019932?c=100454&at=47161) which states it's **without lamp base**, as does [this one](https://www.onlinecarparts.co.uk/car-brands/spare-parts-mercedes-benz/a-class-w176/55767/10554/combination-rearlight.html). What does "without lamp base" mean exactly, and is this what's meant by the label's description of "tail lamp glass"?

This is the back of the light, but being clueless about this stuff, I can't tell based on it whether it's missing anything or whether any lamps are just behind the grey plates.

[image]

Lastly, Van-Wezel and the following [site](https://www.buycarparts.co.uk/van-wezel/7997946) refer to the product as a **combination light** - does this simply mean that it contains both the brakelights and indicators, or is there more to it?

Thanks in advance, it's really appreciated.

Comment: how about open the box and see what you have?

Comment: From the question itself, right above a huge picture of the back of the light: "This is the back of the light, but being clueless about this stuff, I can't tell based on it whether it's missing anything or whether any lamps are just behind the grey plates."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the link you provided . I understood "Tail Lamp Glass R" to refer to the exterior housing assembly on the right hand side.

The lamp base refers to the light socket itself which the  light bulb is physically attached. The lamp base itself is part of the vehicle wiring harness.

A combination light assembly has openings for turn signal, brake, tail light, and reverse light.

Comment: So am I correct in thinking that the product I've bought is the exact same as the product listed on those websites?

Comment: It would appear so....

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I wanted to hear. Thanks for your help.